# Send image and text with OpenGraph FacebookSDK 4.4 in Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working with Facebook SDK 4.4.0 in my Swift App.
Because Facebook forced the removal of prefilled text, I am trying to use Open Graph to post on Facebook content and image from my app.

What I need to do is to send to the Facebook Timeline some text content and also a local image (not on the web). The image is local so it is within the app.

What I achieved until now is to send the local image OR the content, but I want to send both things together.

Here is the Swift code to send the image that works:

```
    @IBAction func facebookButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
        photo.image = UIImage(named: oldImageSaved! as String)
        photo.userGenerated = false

        var content : FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
        content.photos = [photo]

        let button:FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        button.shareContent = content
        button.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
```

And here is the OpenGraph code, that works, to send the content:

```
    @IBAction func facebookButton(sender: UIButton) {

            var current = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentPhrase") as? String
            var currentDescription = current!
            let ImageSaved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentImageSaved") as? NSString

            // Create a FBSDKSharePhoto
            var photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
            photo.image = UIImage(named: ImageSaved! as String)
            photo.userGenerated = false;

            let graphProperties : [NSObject : AnyObject]! = ["og:type": "fbtestapp:testing_test_app", "og:title":"Test App", "og:description": currentDescription]
            var graphObject : FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: graphProperties)

            // Create an action
            var action : FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()

            action.actionType = "fbtestapp:merging"
            action.setObject(graphObject, forKey: "testing_test_app")

            // Create the content
            var content : FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
            content.action = action;
            content.previewPropertyName = "testing_test_app";

            FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)
    }
```

Any help on how can I send local image with some text content with OpenGraph in Swift will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Open Graph actions needs to be approved for an additional capability: `User Messages`. You can read more on that in the [Open Graph Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#capabilities).

This capability needs to be reviewed. When it is approved, you can use the `message` parameter on the `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent` object.

**Be aware:** this is only allowed when the message is coming directly, and only, from the user. If you app is pre-filling this value, it will be blocked and you will not be able to use it.